# How to use the "[" function to select a row / column of a matrix

Tags: r

How can the `"["` function be used to select a column or a row of a matrix?

```
x <- matrix(1:4, ncol=2)
```

As far as I understand, these two lines do the same thing:

```
x[1,2]
"["(x,1,2)
```

Also these two:

```
x[4]
"["(x,4)
```

But how can one rewrite

```
x[2,]
```

using `"["(...) ?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just leave the argument blank

```
"["(x, 2, )   # second row  
[1] 2 4

"["(x,  ,2)    # second column
[1] 3 4
```

Comment: That's so straightforward I feel kind of dumb now. I was actually trying to use "[" in sapply on list of matrices to select 1st row of each matrix with something like "ls = list(x,x);
sapply(ls, "[", 1, ???)" but my failed attempts lead to this question

Comment: The standard R way is to use an anonymous function for this: `sapply(l, function(x) x[1, ])`

Comment: @Ape Try `lapply(l, \`[\`, i = 1, j = )`.  `lapply(l, head, n = 1)` works for rows, but is less general, since you can't do columns.

Comment: @RichieCotton: one issue with that example is that it lets you think `[` matches by name, when it really only matches by position.  Consider: `lapply(l, '[', j=1, i=)` and `lapply(l, '[', , 1)`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Well spotted - I hadn't noticed that `[` had nonstandard argument matching before.  I suppose that makes sense as a feature.  Using named arguments in the wrong order will just lead to awful buggy code.